# SqlCommand select from where issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have got this code below which should:

```
Select column odjezd
From table stanice 
Order by odjezd
where akce=zakce.Text

SqlCommand combobox = new SqlCommand("SELECT odjezd FROM stanice 
                                      ORDER BY odjezd ASC 
                                      WHERE akce="+zakce.Text, spojeni);
```

It gives me this error: Incorrect syntax near `WHERE`.

Would someone please improve my code? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this code:

```
SqlCommand combobox = new SqlCommand("SELECT odjezd FROM stanice WHERE akce='"+zakce.Text + "' ORDER BY odjezd ASC", spojeni);
```

I hope it would work for you.

```
ORDER BY
```

has to go last.

Answer (score 6):

You're `ORDER BY` clause must be last and you are missing the single quotes around your string in `WHERE` clause.

By the way you should use a parameter instead string manipulation for your command text, to prevent from SQL injection.

```
var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT odjezd FROM stanice WHERE akce=@akce ORDER BY odjezd ASC", spojeni);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@akce", zakce.Text));
```

Answer (score 3):

`ORDER BY` has to go for last....

You

- first query for your data
- after order it accordingly

So it will become like:

```
var command new SqlCommand("SELECT odjezd FROM stanice WHERE akce="
                             + zakce.Text + " ORDER BY odjezd ASC", spojeni)
```

Comment: And you ***should always*** use parametrized queries - do not concatenate together your SQL like this - highly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks ....

Answer (score 2):

Where clause goes before order by

Answer (score 1):

ORDER BY should go after WHERE, and I believe you'll need a single quote arount what you're searching for.

```
SqlCommand combobox = new SqlCommand("SELECT odjezd FROM stanice WHERE akce='"+zakce.Text + "' ORDER BY odjezd ASC", spojeni);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is not ordered correctly, a handy run down of SELECT statement ordering can be found here (amongst other places): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

So in your case, you would want to order your statement thusly:

```
SELECT odjezd 
FROM stanice 
WHERE ...
ORDER BY odjezd ASC
```

As Woni has pointed out, it would also be better if you utilised `SqlCommand.Parameters`, to enforce correct data types, and protect you against potential exploits.